# Configuring Raspberry Pi as DHCP/local DNS server, Stretch vs Wheezy

Tags: networking, debian, dhcp, dnsmasq, debian-stretch

I've been using dnsmasq as a DHCP server/resolver on an old Raspberry Pi, running wheezy, for years without any problems. I decided to upgrade to stretch and, at the same time, to a Raspberry Pi 3B+.

Unfortunately, I'm struggling with configuring the new Pi to provide the same DHCP and DNS services as the old Pi. I use dnsmasq for both services. I can configure the new Pi to work properly when it's not also providing DHCP/DNS services, and instead is getting those from the old Pi. But when I try to get it to provide those services, I lose my connection to the internet. It feels like I've messed up configuring the gateway, although I don't know how, and the diagnostics I know how to run don't seem to show a problem with the gateway.

On the old Pi, running wheezy, I configured the ethernet interface in /etc/network/interfaces as follows:

```
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.0.0.4
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.0.0.2
```

On the new Pi, running stretch, I configure the ethernet interface in dhcpcd.conf (note that I'm using a different static IP address here, so the
two devices don't collide while I'm trying to effect the transition to the new device):

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=10.0.0.5/24
static routers=10.0.0.2
```

If I run the new Pi standalone, I comment those three lines out, since then the new Pi gets its IP address from the old Pi.

Under stretch, the boot process seems to involve both resolvconf and dhcpcd rewriting /etc/resolv.conf. Also, resolvconf creates a separate resolv.conf file at /run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf...and the two are not the same. I also don't understand why there are two separate files, and what role each one plays.

Here's /etc/resolv.conf after a boot:

```
# Generated by resolvconf
nameserver 127.0.0.1
# external nameservers
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Here's /run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf:

```
# Generated by resolvconf
```

Here are resolvconf.conf:

```
# Configuration for resolvconf(8)
# See resolvconf.conf(5) for details

resolv_conf=/etc/resolv.conf
# If you run a local name server, you should uncomment the below line and
# configure your subscribers configuration files below.
name_servers=127.0.0.1, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4

# Mirror the Debian package defaults for the below resolvers
# so that resolvconf integrates seemlessly.
dnsmasq_resolv=/var/run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf
pdnsd_conf=/etc/pdnsd.conf
unbound_conf=/var/cache/unbound/resolvconf_resolvers.conf
```

resolv.conf.tail:

```
# external nameservers
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

and dhcpcd.conf:

```
# A sample configuration for dhcpcd.
# See dhcpcd.conf(5) for details.

# Allow users of this group to interact with dhcpcd via the control socket.
#controlgroup wheel

# Inform the DHCP server of our hostname for DDNS.
hostname

# Use the hardware address of the interface for the Client ID.
clientid
# or
# Use the same DUID + IAID as set in DHCPv6 for DHCPv4 ClientID as per RFC4361.
# Some non-RFC compliant DHCP servers do not reply with this set.
# In this case, comment out duid and enable clientid above.
#duid

# Persist interface configuration when dhcpcd exits.
persistent

# Rapid commit support.
# Safe to enable by default because it requires the equivalent option set
# on the server to actually work.
option rapid_commit

# A list of options to request from the DHCP server.
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
# Most distributions have NTP support.
option ntp_servers
# Respect the network MTU. This is applied to DHCP routes.
option interface_mtu

# A ServerID is required by RFC2131.
require dhcp_server_identifier

# Generate Stable Private IPv6 Addresses instead of hardware based ones
slaac private

# A list of options to request from the DHCP server.
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
# Most distributions have NTP support.
option ntp_servers
# Respect the network MTU. This is applied to DHCP routes.
option interface_mtu

# A ServerID is required by RFC2131.
require dhcp_server_identifier

# Generate Stable Private IPv6 Addresses instead of hardware based ones
slaac private

# This section needs to be live if mycroft is serving as
# the DHCP server for the LAN. Conversely, if it isn't
# serving in that role, it needs to be commented out.
interface eth0
static ip_address=10.0.0.5/24
static routers=10.0.0.2
#static domain_name_servers=127.0.0.1,8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4

# not using ip6!
#static ip6_address=fd51:42f8:caae:d92e::ff/64

# domain name servers specified in resolv.conf.tail
#static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8 fd51:42f8:caae:d92e::1

# It is possible to fall back to a static IP if DHCP fails:
# define static profile
#profile static_eth0
#static ip_address=192.168.1.23/24
#static routers=192.168.1.1
#static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1

# fallback to static profile on eth0
#interface eth0
#fallback static_eth0
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Wheezy uses sysvinit, Stretch uses systemd, which automates some network related tasks.

Comment: Thanx, @IporSircer; that's another learning curve I'm trying to come down. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong in the configuration?

Comment: I think your config is ok, just systemd and its network manager think they're smarter than you. (i don't use systemd, i had another strange errors with it.)

Comment: Lol! Right now I’m sure it is smarter than me.